# What episode do Tom Paris and Neelix have a "food fight?"

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, episode-identification

What Voyager episode do Neelix and Paris get in an argument in the dining area, which turns into spaghetti/pasta-on-the-heads/uniforms-fun? I want to watch that episode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're thinking of [2x07- Parturition](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Parturition_%28episode%29):

[image]

From Memory Alpha linked above:

> After an altercation in the mess hall between Neelix and Tom Paris over Kes and involving hair pasta, Captain Janeway has the two of them to go down to a promising planet in a shuttlecraft to search for food supplies while also ordering them to settle their quarrel.

Comment: Notice this is the skinny version of Paris apparently his relation ship with the mess hall improved later in the series lol